# My form controls style is overriding in MVC

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap 3.7 and some additional css is overriding some styles.
My Control length was correct before adding the Bootstrap css 3.7 and its plugin.
now controls width is being short.

When i inspect some of my textbox in browser, system show below applied css styles. plz see and guide.

```
<link href="~/Theme/Bootstrap37/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<link href="~/Theme/Bootstrap37/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Theme/Bootstrap37/css/custom-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@*<link href="~/Theme/Bootstrap37/css/OPD_new.css" rel="stylesheet" />*@
<link href="/Theme/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Theme/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Theme/css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Theme/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Theme/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="~/Theme/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

  .form-group .form-control {
    padding: 7px 12px;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    /* border-color: #f2f2f2; */
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
}
main.css:3128
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #edf8f7;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #8dc6cd;
    /* border-radius: 4px; */
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    height: 49px;
}
forms.less:119
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
forms.less:118
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
scaffolding.less:48
button, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
normalize.less:323
input {
    line-height: normal;
}
normalize.less:257
button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    margin: 0;
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;
}
site.css:22
input, select, textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
bootstrap.css [sm]:1087
input, button, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
normalize.less:322
input {
    line-height: normal;
}
normalize.less:252
button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    margin: 0;
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;
}
bootstrap.css:1062
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
vendor-prefixes.less:77
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
input:not([type]), input[type="email" i], input[type="number" i], input[type="password" i], input[type="tel" i], input[type="url" i], input[type="text" i] {
    padding: 1px 0px;
}
user agent stylesheet
input {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    user-select: text;
    cursor: auto;
    padding: 1px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, select, button {
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
    font: 13.3333px Arial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, select, button, meter, progress {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
Inherited from div.inputgroup
main.css:3324
.inputgroup {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
Inherited from body.homepage
main.css:14
body {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #54667a;
    line-height: 22px;
}
scaffolding.less:32
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}
scaffolding.less:31
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}
Inherited from html.js.flexbox.flexboxlegacy.canvas.canvastext.webgl.no-touch.geolocation.postmessage.websqldatabase.indexeddb.hashchange.history.draganddrop.websockets.rgba.hsla.multiplebgs.backgroundsize.borderimage.borderradius.boxshadow.textshadow.opacity.cssanimations.csscolumns.cssgradients.cssreflections.csstransforms.csstransforms3d.csstransitions.fontface.generatedcontent.video.audio.localstorage.sessionstorage.webworkers.applicationcache.svg.inlinesvg.smil.svgclippaths
scaffolding.less:27
html {
    font-size: 10px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
normalize.less:10
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
bootstrap.css [sm]:1072
html {
    font-size: 10px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
normalize.less:9
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
Pseudo ::before element
bootstrap.css:1068
:after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
vendor-prefixes.less:77
*:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
Pseudo ::after element
bootstrap.css:1068
:after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

vendor-prefixes.less:77
*:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: load bootstrap before you styles in the head that way your styles would override bootstrap if that didn't help use rules of specifity ,, check https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: bootstrap is before other css files. please see in above section now. i have added

Comment: can you please make jsfiddle in order to solve it and please be specific on which styles are affected and you wish to change

Comment: ok i try to make jsfiddle and show u

Comment: Hi Fadi, i am new to js fiddle. can you tell me that how can i upload the resource (css/js) files there ?

Comment: there is a tab on the left called external resources , add the link to cdn and plus sign

Comment: Do I have any way to upload my local css/js files in references and can show you ? or should i have to make a small sample and upload the complete project at some where other than jsfiddle? plz suggest

Comment: maybe https://plnkr.co/ is simpler for you

Comment: i tried plnkr as well but there is no option in that case as well. i can create the js/css files but no upload feature and usage

Comment: plz use this link , i uploaded the files on OneDrive. these are simple , just need to run the index page and click on a text box and inspect it and see in the browser section.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AitLVJhHEke3gol2ziHGwzw8RSwtjA

Comment: ok i have got it whats the problem exactly is it width of elements that have form-control ?

Comment: yes what should i do for it now ?

Comment: if it is not that they are talking full width of parent it is because in site.css you setting input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
remove max-width prop and it will take full width

Comment: Thank you buddy. it is working now :). Have a good day :)

Comment: no problem buddy you too have a good day but please approve the answer to close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input fields  are not taking full width of parent it is because in your
site.css file you have

```
input,select, textarea { max-width: 280px; }
```

remove max-width prop and it will take full width